# Remove device that was added to qemu/kvm without a short id

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm

I have a KVM virtual machine that I would rather not restart.  A USB device was added to it using the qemu monitor `device_add` command without specifying an id. I want to unplug the device so it can be attached to a different VM. All the information I can find online suggests using `device_del` and giving it the devices id, which clearly won't work because I didn't give it one.

Is there another way of removing it without restarting the VM?  I see a [patch was submitted to allow an alternative syntax several years ago](https://qemu-devel.nongnu.narkive.com/SjM9DqXt/patch-v4-monitor-allow-device-del-to-accept-qom-paths) but I'm not sure if the patch was ever included, or if somebody found a different way to fix this problem.  If the patch was included, how do I use it?  I'm not sure what a QOM path for my device would look like or how I'd find it.  Some responses to the patch suggested automatically generating ids for devices that don't have one; if this happened, how do I find the automatic id?  Is there another way?